# How to download files (pdf, doc etc...) into sdcard and open the file using volley in android?

Tags: android, file, download, android-volley

In my android app i need to download a file into my SD card and view it through intents, I'm using volley library for all network calls in my application.
Ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {     
        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%           progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
            // setting downloaded into image view

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can see in my question that i want to implement using volley library. Anyway thanks for your response

Comment: Volley Doesnt Provide Any Request For Downloading Files Like Pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot .. its working fine. Can you help me on how to upload files...( using volley if it supports)?

Comment: yes send me your email  i will send you some helpful resources for uploading

Comment: What happen if connection is lost when download progress at 50%, Try to modify the code for proper breaking of loop if connection was lost